# Can i update a non-nullable value in an Entity by using Update method from Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have already created an entity but want to update a value of a non-nullable column. I use the Update method from EF to try this but doesnt work. Is it possible to update a non-nullable value?

```
    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
    }
```

Comment: `Update` doesn't talk to the database. DbContext isn't a database connection. No tutorial contains code like this. Did you try copying code from unfortunate articles or questions about EF perhaps? Articles that try to implement the repository **anti**pattern? You should understand how ORMs in general and EF in particular work first, not jump straight to implementation

Comment: A DbContext isn't a connection. It's a disconnected Unit-of-Work. A DbSet isn't a table, it's a Repository that works in a disconnected way. The DbContext collects all modifications made to the entities it controls and sends *all* of them to the database when `SaveChanges` is called, in a transaction. Until then it doesn't even keep a connection to the database. That's what makes it fast, scaleable and gives you transaction semantics without the transaction cost.  Neither is broken, neither needs fixing or an explicit `Update` method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ofcourse I use SaveChanges at another place. But it should be possible to update non-nullable value?

Comment: Why did you write a separate `Update` then? One that duplicates the existing one? And what does nullability have to do with database updates? This code is very suspicious and looks like an attempt to "fix" what isn't broken, and impose a repository on top of EF Core. Given that DbSet is the repository and DbContext the UoW containing multiple repositories,  this tries to reverse how EF works and always results in trouble

Answer (score 1):

just add SaveChanges()

```
 public void Update(T entity)
{
    _context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```